# How can I resolve SQL Server file attachment error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-config-manager

I want to attach a `sql.mdf` file with database I have, but I get the following error; I also run it as administrator but still get that error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeTmQ.png)

I get SQL Server remote error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdLmI.png)

I apply SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x86-ENU but I get error no the SQL Server service instance or feature update

My system is service pack 1

```
SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as 'Product Version',
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as 'Service Pack', 
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Edition',
    SERVERPROPERTY('instancename') as 'Instance',
    SERVERPROPERTY('servername') as 'Server Name
```

It returns the following result

```
10.0.2531.0     SP1    Express Edition     NULL     SALMANRAJPOOT
```

I'm very disappointed from all these error my system is 32 bit and my visual studio 2010 and windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to restore a database created in SQL Server 2012, to a SQL Server 2008 instance. This isn't going to work. Instead I suggest using the Copy Database Wizard.

Before you start, ensure that the database has a comparability level of 100.

In the Copy Database wizard, select the 2012 instance as the source.

Select the 2008 instance as the destination.

Select SMO (Server Management Objects) as the transfer method.